# Trigonometry: Where do these extra values come from?

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

I understand where the 2 values come from.

$\pi/12$ and $5\pi/12$

The first value is found by calculating $\sin^{-1}(0.5)$.

The second by subtracting $\pi$ to the result.

But I have no idea as to how $13\pi/12$ and $17\pi/12$ got there.

Answer (score 3):

Since you want all possible values of $x$ where $0 \leq x \leq 2 \pi$, that means you want all values of $x$ where $0 \leq 2x \leq 4\pi$ (as noted in the image you linked to). Two such values are $2x=\pi/6$ and $x=5\pi/6$. If you add $2\pi$ to these values, their sine does not change, so you will get more potential values of $2x$ which satisfy the equation $\sin(2x)=0.5$. So $\pi/6+2\pi, \pi/6+4\pi,\pi/6+6\pi, \dots$ and $5\pi/6+2\pi, 5\pi/6+4\pi,5\pi/6+6\pi,\dots$ are all possible values for $2x$. You only want the ones in the range from $0$ to $4\pi$, which leaves $2x=\pi/6+2\pi=13\pi/6$ and $2x=5\pi/6+2\pi=17\pi/6$. Thus $x=13\pi/12$ and $x=17\pi/12$ are also solutions in the range you want.

Answer (score 2):

They are just adding $2\pi$ to the results of $\pi/6$ and $5\pi/6$ since adding $2\pi$ doesn't change the value of $\sin{x}$.